# How XAMPP 1.7.3 can support PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.2 and other lower PHP

Tags: php, xampp, wamp, wampserver

I would like to know how to setup XAMPP Server with multiple PHP versions (eg PHP 5.3, 5.2, 5, and 4), I know WAMP can easily do this, But I have problem with a WP Plugin using WAMP. Now if XAMPP can support PHP version, It would make my life easy and organize; Compare to installing both WAMP and XAMPP (that I did last time, before I formated my workstation. Now I wont do that again if I have options).

note: I'm using Windows 7 and installed XAMPP 1.7.3.

Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but maybe something to think about: ditch *AMPP and use vmware or virtualbox – setup different images with different PHP versions. This also has the advantage that you are developing on the same OS and same configuration setup that your application is deployed too (I guess you dont use windows 7 for hosting your application).

Answer (score 0):

im running xammp and on my control panel for it i have a tab that says php version. inside that tab is a button that says "Activate PHP4"

check out this thread

https://superuser.com/questions/123902/getting-xampp-to-work-with-multiple-version-of-php

Comment: lol, it's same thread. But It's not the answer I'm looking for. I'm hopping to support PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.2 not only PHP 4. I also tried that solution. But It only supports PHP 4 and is using XAMPP 1.6